# Flagging "Comment" Answers

Tags: support, flags, moderator-abilities

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Feature Request: Ability to flag an answer as “not an answer” or “should be a comment”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40906/feature-request-ability-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer-or-should-be-a-com)
>   [Should moderators be able to convert answers into comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments)

I've flagged certain answers as for moderator attention, noting that they should be comments. However, do moderators have any power to do anything in these situations, or should I instead not flag and just comment on the answer.

Comment: Moderators _can_ do many things about the issue, but it's best to also leave a comment telling the offending user what they did wrong (and how to fix it in the future). Also, if they don't have enough rep to comment, I like to upvote them to help them on their way.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40906/feature-request-ability-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer-or-should-be-a-com and also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/comments-incorrectly-submitted-as-an-answer-instead-what-should-we-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't transform it from an answer to a comment (by the same author), so in most cases I just leave a comment suggesting that the author make it a comment themselves.  If it's a truly content-free response, or if the author's account has been abandoned, I might just delete it.  The newer the answer or user leaving the answer, the less likely I am to delete.

Answer (score 1):

They can delete them. If the content is especially valuable, they could potentially add it to a comment, but there's no automated support for this.

#### See: [Should moderators be able to convert answers into comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply flag the answer as spam, which gives the user an immediate (small) hit to their reputation and has the potential of giving them a bigger hit if 5 other people agree with you that this is spam.

Comment: The thing is, most of these users are new to SO and if they've earned a small but significant amount of rep to them, I don't want them to be penalized for it.