# Can there be an explicit verbage for "noise" added to the flag an answer dialog?

Tags: feature-request, flags

In the flag answer dialog we have the following option:

> not an answer
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment(*), another question, or deleted altogether.

Presumably, this(*) is the option we should use for 'noise' answers. However, it doesn't spell it out. If someone posts something terrible like "first", how are we to flag it? If it is using this answer, could "noise" be added as a qualifier for this option?

I saw a [corollary post to this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40906/feature-request-ability-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer-or-should-be-a-com), and I'm not sure if Jeff's response will be the same, but again this is at the minimum to add 'noise' as a stated option.

*(If I should just be using another option please let me know.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it serve any use or purpose to stick around or should it be wrapped up as a clay pigeon and blasted apart to nothing?

For noise posts that aren't answers, the "not an answer" option is the correct one.

The last bit, "or deleted altogether", is the one to heed since noise is deleted on sight by the moderators.

Comment: Serves no use, and was barely amusing (i.e. qualified, maybe, as a 'comment' status). For the noise I am referring to it should be blasted apart; the example I have in mind is one such example. I just didn't see "noise", and it seems like having that explicitly stated should be an option.

Comment: But it's still not an answer. Noise is just a synonym. @mfg

Comment: Sounds good, was just curious since there was 'noise' under the comment flag and was wondering about parity between dialogs. I just realized it looks from the title like there should be another 'option', i just meant for the verbage to be added to the existing option... will adjust